# XSLT2.0 adding based on condition in current-group()

Tags: xml, xslt

Changing the xmls to make these more close to the actual transformation required.

Pls consider the xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns0:MyFile xmlns:ns0="http://myfile.com">
  <RECORDS>
     <Detail>
        <Groupby>Group1</Groupby>
        <Cond>10</Cond>
        <AddMe>200</AddMe>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <Groupby>Group1</Groupby>
        <Cond>12</Cond>
         <AddMe>1200</AddMe>
    </Detail>
     <Detail>
        <Groupby>Group1</Groupby>
        <Cond>22</Cond>
         <AddMe>1200</AddMe>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <Groupby>Group1</Groupby>
         <Cond>11</Cond>
         <AddMe>200</AddMe>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
         <Groupby>Group2</Groupby>
         <Cond>11</Cond>
        <AddMe>230</AddMe>
    </Detail>
     <Detail>
        <Groupby>Group2</Groupby>
        <Cond>12</Cond>
        <AddMe>1200</AddMe>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
         <Groupby>Group2</Groupby>
         <Cond>10</Cond>
        <AddMe>200</AddMe>
     </Detail>
     <Detail>
        <Groupby>Group2</Groupby>
        <Cond>22</Cond>
        <AddMe>1300</AddMe>
     </Detail>
  </RECORDS>
</ns0:MyFile>
```

Desired Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns0:ResultFile xmlns:ns0="http://myfile.com">
 <Results>
    <Detail>    <!--Based on ((Cond = 10) or (Cond = 11)) for Group1 -->
        <Constant0>RIDE</Constant0> 
        <Group>Group1</Group>
        <Added>400</Added>
        <Constant1>BIKE</Constant1>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>        <!--Based on (OTHERS, any OTHER Cond) for Group1 -->
        <Constant0>RIDE</Constant0>
        <Group>Group1</Group>
        <Added>2400</Added>
        <Constant1>CAR</Constant1>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>    <!--Based on ((Cond = 10) or (Cond = 11)) for Group2 -->
        <Constant0>RIDE</Constant0> 
        <Group>Group1</Group>
        <Added>430</Added>
        <Constant1>BIKE</Constant1>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>        <!--Based on (OTHERS, any OTHER Cond) for Group2 -->
        <Constant0>RIDE</Constant0>
        <Group>Group1</Group>
        <Added>2500</Added>
        <Constant1>CAR</Constant1>
    </Detail>
 </Results>
```

Following the previous solution provided by Michael, i used the code below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://myfile.com">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:ResultFile xmlns:ns0="http://myfile.com">
        <Results>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="((//Cond = 11) or (//Cond = 10))">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="ns0:MyFile/RECORDS/Detail" group-by="concat(Groupby, '|', ((Cond = 11) or (Cond = 10 )))">

                <xsl:value-of select="(current-group())"/>
                        <Detail>
                            <Constant0>RIDE</Constant0>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="Groupby"/>
                    <AddMe>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/AddMe)"/>
                    </AddMe>
                            <Constant1>BIKE</Constant1>
                        </Detail>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>

                <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
                        <Detail>
                            <Constant0>RIDE</Constant0>
                            <Constant1>CAR</Constant1>
                        </Detail>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Results>
    </ns0:ResultFile>
</xsl:template>
```

Result I get is fine in terms of sums but then I am unable to have two separate Constants in Group segments. Result below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns0:ResultFile xmlns:ns0="http://myfile.com">
<Results>
    <Detail>
        <Constant0>RIDE</Constant0>
        <Groupby>Group1</Groupby>
        <AddMe>400</AddMe>
        <Constant1>BIKE</Constant1>
    </Detail>
     <Detail>
        <Constant0>RIDE</Constant0>
        <Groupby>Group1</Groupby>
        <AddMe>2400</AddMe>
        <Constant1>BIKE</Constant1>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <Constant0>RIDE</Constant0>
        <Groupby>Group2</Groupby>
        <AddMe>430</AddMe>
        <Constant1>BIKE</Constant1>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <Constant0>RIDE</Constant0>
        <Groupby>Group2</Groupby>
        <AddMe>2500</AddMe>
        <Constant1>BIKE</Constant1>
    </Detail>
</Results>
```

Comment: Why don't you post your stylesheet so we can fix it, instead of writing your code for from scratch?

Comment: Will do that in my next request. I just didn't want the post to be looong :) ...looks like i've to edit this post only... thrs a limit to posts for me/newcomers

Comment: You really should  have posted this changed requirement  as a new question. What determines the value of `Constant1`?

Comment: I really wanted this change as a new question but there are few rules thr abt it apparently. Constant is just there for each group, totally hard-coded. Also, I am very new to xslt, didn't ve any training. was just given stylus studio and one working example to learn from :) I'm just trying to learn at this point.

Comment: did u mark me -1 :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> unable to pass a variable into a xslt-function to do the sum in
>   another for-each.

I don't see why you would need (or want) to do anything like that, when you can do simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://myfile.com">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:MyFile">
    <ns0:ResultFile>
        <Results>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="RECORDS/Detail" group-by="concat(Gorupby, '|' , Cond)">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Gorupby"/>
                    <AddMe>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/AddMe)" />
                    </AddMe>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Cond"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Results>
    </ns0:ResultFile>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To adapt this to your new requirement, change:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="RECORDS/Detail" group-by="concat(Gorupby, '|' , Cond)">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="RECORDS/Detail" group-by="string-join((Groupby, string(Cond=10 or Cond=11)), '|')">
```

Comment: The actual task is bit different from what i described earlier. Will create another post. Thanks a ton for your help... appreciate a lot.

Comment: can't create another post today so i'll edit this one only

Comment: No result at all now. <?xml version='1.0' ?>
<ns0:ResultFile xmlns:ns0="http://myfile.com"><Results/></ns0:ResultFile> tried few other changes but no real results.

Comment: in the requirement the target structure is different. It has constant1, which is different for one condition (Cond = 10 and 11) and different for the others. When the 'Added' is for Cond = 10 and 11, 'Constant1' = BIKE for rest of the Cond, 'Constant1' = CAR.

Comment: So use `<Constant1><xsl:value-of select="if (Cond=10 or Cond=11) then 'BIKE' else 'CAR'" /></Constant1>`.

Comment: yup... awesome... works gr8... thanks a ton again :)

Comment: thanks mate, didn't know about accepting the answer. Just did that. I don't get any alerts for comments to my posts.