XSLT : Sum and remove xml nodes based on conditions
I'm currently working on a tricky transformation in which I need to sum the amount of the game articles price value when the article appears twice and to exclude the second article from the output.
Explanation : Each article has a id, name, price and a copy number. In my case, I always have two copies. Copy 0 & Copy 1. If an article has two copies, then we add the price of article copy 1 in article copy 0 and we exclude copy 1 from the output
I'm not exactly sure on how to approach this requirement.
The XML input
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wd:Report_Data>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:id>1000</wd:id>
    <wd:name>Call of Duty</wd:name>
    <wd:price>50.12</wd:price>
    <wd:copy>0</wd:copy>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:id>1000</wd:id>
    <wd:name>Call of Duty</wd:name>
    <wd:price>60.0</wd:price>
    <wd:copy>1</wd:copy>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:id>2000</wd:id>
    <wd:name>Metal Slug</wd:name>
    <wd:price>75.00</wd:price>
    <wd:copy>0</wd:copy>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:id>3000</wd:id>
    <wd:name>Need For Speed</wd:name>
    <wd:price>40.00</wd:price>
    <wd:copy>0</wd:copy>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>

The expected XML output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wd:Report_Data>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:id>1000</wd:id>
    <wd:name>Call of Duty</wd:name>
    <wd:price>110.12</wd:price>
    <wd:copy>0</wd:copy>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:id>2000</wd:id>
    <wd:name>Metal Slug</wd:name>
    <wd:price>75.00</wd:price>
    <wd:copy>0</wd:copy>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:id>3000</wd:id>
    <wd:name>Need For Speed</wd:name>
    <wd:price>40.00</wd:price>
    <wd:copy>0</wd:copy>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>

Following @michael.hor257k recommendation, I was able to create a grouping structure and sum the price. However, I still don't get the expected result
XSLT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:wd="http://www.workday.org/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry" group-by="wd:id">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="wd:id"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="wd:name"/>
                    <wd:price>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/wd:price)" />
                    </wd:price>                 
                    <xsl:copy-of select="wd:copy"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Result (not what I want )
<wd:Report_Entry xmlns:wd="http://www.workday.org/">
   <wd:id>1000</wd:id>
   <wd:name>Call of Duty</wd:name>
   <wd:price xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">110.12</wd:price>
   <wd:copy>0</wd:copy>
</wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Report_Entry xmlns:wd="http://www.workday.org/">
   <wd:id>2000</wd:id>
   <wd:name>Metal Slug</wd:name>
   <wd:price xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">75</wd:price>
   <wd:copy>0</wd:copy>
</wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Report_Entry xmlns:wd="http://www.workday.org/">
   <wd:id>3000</wd:id>
   <wd:name>Need For Speed</wd:name>
   <wd:price xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">40</wd:price>
   <wd:copy>0</wd:copy>
</wd:Report_Entry>


There is nothing "tricky" about this; it's a basic  grouping problem. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 and higher.

Perfect. I'll give it a try

@michael.hor257k - Could you please guide me a little bit? I understand the use of the grouping functions like (for-each & for-each-group). However, I'm confused on how to build a mechanism that sums only in the article (with copy = 0).

I don't understand the difficulty: just group the entries by their id and sum the group's prices. A group of 1 is a group just like any other.

Here's an example you could use as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39185213/3016153

@michael.hor257k - My xml output does not look correct. I'm guessing it that the issue is due to the match path I have chosen. I tried multiple combinations, but without further result

You only need to make a few small changes:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:wd="http://www.workday.org/">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/wd:Report_Data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry" group-by="wd:id">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="wd:id"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="wd:name"/>
                <wd:price>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/wd:price)" />
                </wd:price>                 
                <xsl:copy-of select="wd:copy"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

